# updating file path list in a fast changing directory

Tags: python, indexing, information-retrieval

I have a directory that I visit from time to time to check its contents, so I have created this code to retrieve list paths of all the files within this  directory and its subdirectories:

```
our_dir='c:\\mydocs'
walk=os.walk(our_dir)

for path, folders, files in walk:
    for f in files:
        file_path=os.path.join(path,f)
        print file_path
```

This directory has 200K+ files and frequent file changes and additions, so while the code finishes running, more files will have been added/changed. The question is how to do the following:

1. conduct an initial run for the code, to list all the file paths
   in this directory that were created/changed before the initial run
   starting time
2. Store somehow the files added/changed during the
   initial run (between the initial run start time and the initial run end time)
3. with every subsequent run, list only the paths
   created before the current run- and after the end time of the initial run, and during the current run (between the current run start time and the current run end time)

Any idea on how to do this? I just want to make it clear that I am not "watching/monitoring" the directory, but I am visiting it from time to time.

Comment: Are you asking about the implementation or the algorithm? Because your algorithm sounds very naive (and working), and the implementation sounds pretty straight-forward (using `time` module).

Comment: yes it is naive, the problem is how to list all the file paths while all these changes happen simultaneously. I don't think this algorithm is efficient (will need to check the modification time for each and every file during each run) and I think there is something better.

Comment: What about running `os.system`\`os.popen` etc. to run 'dir' or 'ls' ? They do it most efficiently

Comment: I would consider writing a data structure representing the file tree to a dictionary and saving this as a .json file. You could then recreate the dictionary on subsequent runs to compare to the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a really basic structure idea: each folder gets it's own thread. You would have 2 classes, one that gathers the data "directoryHelper", and one to store it "Directory".

Two classes are required because a thread can only be started once, and you need to be able to generate a new thread for a directory that has already been listed without losing it's data.

The root directory would be a Directory instance that lists it's given path ('C:\mydocs'). It would store the file list in self.files and create a new Directory instance for every directory it contains (without forgetting to them in self.dirs to be able to access them.

Refreshing could be timed, and checks for the directory's modification date as you suggested.

Here's some code to help you understand my idea:

```
class Helper(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, directory):
    super(Helper, self).__init__()
    self.directory = directory
    self.start()

  def run(self):
    for path, folders, files in os.walk(self.directory.path):
      for f in files:
          self.directory.files.append(os.path.join(path, f))

      for d in folders:
          self.directory.dirs.append(Directory(os.path.join(path, d), self.directory.interval, self.directory.do))

    self = None

class Directory(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, path, interval=5, do=None):
    super(Directory, self).__init__()
    self.path = path
    self.files, self.dirs = ([], [])
    self.interval = interval
    self.last_update = 0
    self.helper = None

    self.do = do # One flag to stop refreshing all instances
    if do == None:
      self.do = True

  def run(self):
    while self.do:
      self.refresh()
      time.sleep(self.interval)

  def refresh(self):
    # Only start a refresh if there self.helper is done and directory was changed
    if not self.helper and self.has_changed():
      self.last_update = int(time.time())
      self.helper = Helper(self)

  def has_changed(self):
    return int(os.path.getmtime(self.path)) > self.last_update
```

I think this should be enough to get you started!

Edit: I changed the code a bit to actually be in a working state. Or at least I hope it is (I haven't tested it)!

Edit 2: I actually took the time to test this, and fix it. I ran:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  root = Directory('/home/plg')
  root.refresh()
  root.helper.join()

  for d in [root] + root.dirs:
    for f in d.files:
      print f
```

And:

```
$ time python bin/dirmon.py | wc -l # wc -l == len(sys.stdout.readlines())
7805

real  0m0.078s
user  0m0.048s
sys 0m0.028s
```

That's 7805 / 0.078 = 100,064 files per second. Not too bad! :)

Edit 3 (last one!):
I ran the test on '/', first run (without cache):
147551 / 4.103 = 35,961 files per second

Second and third:

```
$ time python bin/dirmon.py | wc -l
147159

real  0m1.213s
user  0m0.940s
sys 0m0.272s
$ time python bin/dirmon.py | wc -l
147159

real  0m1.209s
user  0m0.928s
sys 0m0.284s
```

147551 / 1.213 = 121,641 files per second

147551 / 1.209 = 122,044 files per second